# RVM warning when installing Passenger on the Mac

Tags: passenger

Installing Passenger on the Mac runs into this problem. 
Any suggestions?

```
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module

...

 * Checking for Zlib development headers...
  Found: yes
  Location: /usr/local/include/zlib.h
Your RVM wrapper scripts are too old, or some wrapper scripts are missing. Please update/regenerate them first by running:

rvmsudo rvm get stable && rvm reload && rvmsudo rvm repair all

If that doesn't seem to work, please run:

rvmsudo rvm wrapper [] --no-prefix --all
```

First I did:

```
$  rvmsudo rvm get stable && rvm reload && rvmsudo rvm repair all
Warning: can not check `/etc/sudoers` for `secure_path`, falling back to call via `/usr/bin/env`, this breaks rules from `/etc/sudoers`. export rvmsudo_secure_path=1 to avoid the warning.
```

which re-installed rvm and then I did:

```
$  rvmsudo rvm wrapper [] --no-prefix --all
Warning: can not check `/etc/sudoers` for `secure_path`, falling back to call via `/usr/bin/env`, this breaks rules from `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

export rvmsudo_secure_path=1

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.

In case there is no `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

export rvmsudo_secure_path=0

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.
awk: nonterminated character class ^[]=
source line number 1
context is
>>> /^[]=/ <<< 
sed: 1: "s#^[]=##
": unbalanced brackets ([])
Unknown ruby interpreter string component: '[]'.
Could not load ruby [].
```

Answer (score 2):

Add to your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile

```
export rvmsudo_secure_path=0
```

You may try to install passenger without sudo.

```
$ passenger-install-apache2-module
```